# Is there a way to display metabox in frontend? How?

Tags: metabox, front-end

I was wondering if there is a way how to show the metabox in frontend.

What i want to achieve:
I want to be able to use the metabox to edit posts from frontend the same way i do it from backend.

Thanks!